# curl_exec not working inside a loop

Tags: php, loops, curl

I have a class with the function below. When I call that function directly it works, but if I call that function inside the loop I got an error: `Cannot connect to host`. Can somebody help me? :) Thanks in advance.

```
public function exportProfile($xml) {

        $_myRequest = curl_init("https://www.example.com/postProfile");

        curl_setopt($_myRequest, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($_myRequest, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "testUser:testPassword");
        curl_setopt($_myRequest, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: application/xml"));
        curl_setopt($_myRequest, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$xml );
        curl_setopt($_myRequest, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        // do request, the response text is available in $_response
        $_response = curl_exec($_myRequest);

        $err = curl_error($_myRequest) ;

        echo $err;

        $_statusCode = curl_getinfo($_myRequest, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        // close cURL resource, and free up system resources
        curl_close($_myRequest);

        return simplexml_load_string($_response);       
    }
```

Comment: `testUser:testPassword");` Should that `"` be there? Or should there be one in front of testuser?

Comment: Can you show the loop that fails?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce that problem with a simple example. Your example code seems to have a syntax error in `CURLOPT_USERPWD`, but I assume that is not related.

It sounds quite likely that there could there be rate limiting on the site you are querying, i.e. when you hit them a few times in a row they lock you out.

Perhaps you could debug by trying to run the query multiple times outside of the loop, i.e. calling it 1/2/3 times manually.

Comment: Yeahh i see i have a syntax error but that is not related. I believe is a synchronization problem or something similar with the curl functions. Lets say i have a method exportProfile($xml): this method send an xml to certain address, i have another method called sendProfiles() in the same class, this method uses a loop to call exportProfile($xml). When i call sendProfiles() from a php page that uses my class, is when i get the error. On other hand if in the same php page create a loop and start calling exportProfile($xml) inside the loop, then the xportProfile($xml) function works.